# REGEX - Find any occurance of a comma between two words

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, t-sql

I am trying to find old formated SQL statements that are not compatible in MS SQL 2008/2012. What I'd like to find is the use of commas used to seporate table names in the "from" clause but before the "where" clause.

**SQL example of an old way of quering multi. tables in TSQL:**

> Select *
>
> from test,
>
> ```
>   test2, 
>
>   test3
> ```
>
> where test1.abc = 1

The statements can be on multi. lines and may contain none to several commas.

Comment: What language are you executing regex with?

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't think this will capture everything (e.g. think about CTEs and subqueries, queries without where clauses, queries without from where you expect, etc.), and it can probably return false positives, but maybe:

```
WHERE LOWER(definition) LIKE '%from%,%where%';
```

If you need something more elaborate and reliable, you will need to use CLR, as there is no RegEx support in T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use [these CLR functions](http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/how-to/regex-efficient-sql-querying) that support working with groups and captures. It's just a wrapper over RegEx class in .NET and sooner or later you'll need to use RegEx in your T-SQL code.